# Unable to run Heroku CLI from Windows Ubuntu Bash

Tags: bash, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to run Heroku CLI on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. When I do `heroku create` or any other heroku command, I get this error:

```
 ▸    waitid: invalid argument
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/muz/.cache/heroku/tmp/heroku-script-028766835'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3
```

I've tried installing all the requirements: node, ruby, npm, git and it still doesn't run.

I have also tried deleting the `heroku` folder within `.cache`. I don't know why it's checking within this folder.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting `~/.local/share/heroku` and reinstalling. Reinstalling without deleting the folder didn't work.